# How to build a separate kernel in the home directory

Tags: kernel

I'm a linux newbie. 
How does one build a separate kernel on the home directory other than the usual /usr/src/linux location.
Is it possible to do so?
Can someone elaborate the steps?

Answer (score 0):

Please see The Ubuntu Kernel Team wiki page https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelTeam/GitKernelBuild

You can build a kernel anywhere you want, you do not need to su root or
anything to build a kernel.

Also see, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Dev and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel

Which has a page for about every kernel hacking topic you can think of.